# Why were VP's proxies sabotaged in David Marusek's "Cabbages and Kale"?

Tags: david-marusek

In David Marusek's story "Cabbages and Kale: Or, How We Downsized North America," the protagonist is Saul Jespersen, Vice President of the United States. In this future, people often use "proxies"--computer simulations of themselves--"cast" from their own minds, to do various business for them, with the originals trusting the proxies to act as they would.

So in this story, there is a very important proposed law about to be put to a vote in the American Congress. This law would ban procreation (with extremely rare, authorized exceptions), because current medicine/technology has made it possible for people to stop aging, and live indefinitely.

Now, Jespersen discovers that his proxies are expressing highly controversial views that are completely unlike him, which seems to be caused by some sort of sabotage. Near the end of the story, he learns that

> his boss, the President

is behind it, in order to

> make him vote in favor of the procreation ban.

What is unclear to me is, how does sabotaging his proxies help them to achieve that goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have hard evidence at hand right now (will dig back into the story later on and look for some supporting quotes), but my impression is that the sabotage, once Jesperson discovers it, basically acts like a threat, showing that the saboteur in question has serious power to mess with his life, thus serving as blackmail to nudge Jesperson towards a certain action.

The threat is very strong because, in this particular universe, proxies basically operate with all the authority of their owner.  Being able to control someone's proxy is tantamount to being able to control the person himself, since you could get the proxy to enter into binding agreements on the person's behalf.

The same universe is explored much more fully in Marusek's two novels "Counting Heads" and "Mind Over Ship", so my supporting quotes may end up coming from those other works.  Certainly my impression of the significance of proxy-tampering is based on those two novels, and not just on what's in the short story you reference.

Comment: OK, that pretty much makes sense. 
Only, why wouldn't the saboteur let him know what they wanted him to do or not do? A threat isn't effective if it's not understood.
(I've read his novels too BTW.)

Comment: Sorry, not ignoring.  Will follow up with supporting quotes, and perhaps even input from David Marusek himself (he known to correspond with readers, so maybe he'll get on SE here?).  The explanation I'll probably put forward in this answer (later) is that the "what they wanted him to do or not do" becomes clear at the end of the story, and the reveal is a ~surprise for the reader.  Yeah, it might be more straightforward for the blackmailer to say, "I did X to you, and now I want you to do Y", but it's more ominous if it's just left as a vague mystery threat for a while ("JFK"-style).